# Showing boundedness of the function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be metric space, consider $f: M \to R$, $f(z) = d(x,z) - d(y,z)$.
I need to show that $f(z)$ is bounded. From triangle identity we easily get $f(z) \leq d(x,y)$, so we have the upper bound. I belive that $|f(z)| \leq d(x,y)$ is true, but how to find the lower bound or prove my assumption?

Comment: $-f(z) = d(y,z) - d(x,z) \le d(y,x) = d(x,y) $ (by the triangle inequality), so $|f(z)| \le d(x,y)$.

Comment: Please, you need to fix $x,y$ at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic result: $|d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y,z \in M$.
Note that $-f(z) = d(x,z) - d(y,z) \leq |d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$.